# EJB giving wrong output

Tags: ejb-3.0

I am calling local EJB which fetches me some list of comments .Here every comment has a specific date of creation.From this I need to fetch the latest comment So what I do is I check the latest time and then use this  time to fetch the latest comment and display it on UI

Now while testing the same I am facing a problem that in  UI it is not displaying the latest comment but comment before the latest comment for some time duration .

For ex :

I have comment1,comment2,comment3,comment4 created where comment1 ia the oldest and comment4 is the latest

Now when I am running my application I am getting comment3 in the output not comment4 which is expected but after some time around an hour when I run the application again I could see comment4 .

Also when I check the logs I am actually not getting the comment4 from the EJB **initially** Now this EJB is also deployed as a webservice When I run this webservice at the same time I could see the comment4 as well

Is this any cache issue. I am not able to understand what is the issue

Please let me know if more details required

Comment: Please provide the way you get latest comment as well as the code how you persist them (if you do persist them at all).

Answer (score 0):

to obtain the comments you might have used a JPQL as I presume

```
SELECT MAX(time) from comments
```

in this way you could get the latest comment with the timestamp

check if your query the data correctly ..

Comment: Please see below the logic of fetching the latest date . Now based on this date I extract the latest comment                    private Date getLatestNoteDate(List<AlarmNoteHistoryDTO> noteHistory ) {
    
     Date tempDate=noteHistory.get(0).getTimeStamp();
     

    
        

    
      for(AlarmNoteHistoryDTO alarmHistory:noteHistory) {
        

        
          if(alarmHistory.getTimeStamp().after(tempDate)) {
            tempDate=alarmHistory.getTimeStamp();
          }
          
         return tempDate;
      }

Comment: this is correct but if the noteHistory list is very large in size, then consider performance as well.. getting the date filtered with JPQL in DTO itself will be good in terms of performance isn't it so?

Comment: I have some constraint that i cannot do this with JPQL

Answer (score 0):

Please see below the logic of fetching the latest date . Now based on this date I extract the latest comment

```
private Date getLatestNoteDate(List<AlarmNoteHistoryDTO> noteHistory ) {    
  Date tempDate=noteHistory.get(0).getTimeStamp();    
  for(AlarmNoteHistoryDTO alarmNoteHistory:noteHistory) {        
      if(alarmNoteHistory.getTimeStamp().after(tempDate)) {
        tempDate=alarmNoteHistory.getTimeStamp();
      }  
     return tempDate;
  }
```